# Add percentage sign to column of numbers in bootstrap-vue table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Suppose I have this table created using `bootstrap-vue`.

Table looks like this;
[image]

The code for this table is as follows;

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        // Note 'isActive' is left out and will not appear in the rendered table
        fields: [
          {
            key: 'last_name',
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            key: 'first_name',
            sortable: false
          },
          {
            key: 'age',
            label: 'Person age',
            sortable: true,
            // Variant applies to the whole column, including the header and footer
            variant: 'danger'
          }
        ],
        items: [
          { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
          { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
          { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
          { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I would like to add percentage sign as a suffix to the numbers in the `Age` column but the column is to remain sortable according to the number value. How can the code be modified to do this?

The code example is extracted from link below;
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table

I am using vue.js v2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can directly modify your data, you can simply use `Array.prototype.map`:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
        { age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
        { age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
        { age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
      ].map(item => (
        item.age = item.age + "%",
        item
      )),
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. I'm not sure if this column remains sortable according to number value after adding the % sign this way. Let me test out.

Comment: @user3848207 Okay. I expect it would sort based on alphabetical, not numerical order, giving unexpected effects. I can't seem to find a custom sort function in the docs, if you do that would make life easier. Or, you can assign custom classes to every item in the `age` column and render a CSS `:after` effect: `.age-column::after { content: "%"; }`.

Comment: @code, the formatter function in bootstrapvue will make life easier to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward implementation is to use the formatted callback function provided in BootstrapVue to add the percentage sign. Next, set the field property `sortByFormatted` to false so that sorting is done according to the unformatted original number values.

Relevant documentation links;
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#formatter-callback
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#field-definition-reference

Here's the code change needed;

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        // Note 'isActive' is left out and will not appear in the rendered table
        fields: [
          {
            key: 'last_name',
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            key: 'first_name',
            sortable: false
          },
          {
            key: 'age',
            label: 'Person age',
            sortable: true,
            // Variant applies to the whole column, including the header and footer
            variant: 'danger',
            //Code modification needed. Add the 2 properties below;
            "sortByFormatted": false,
            formatter: value => {
                return (value + '%')
            },          
          }
        ],
        items: [
          { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
          { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
          { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
          { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```